# In Kotlin, is it possible to limit a function parameter to 2 class types instead of Any?

Tags: generics, inheritance, kotlin, multiple-inheritance

I'm checking permissions and I can do that with either a Fragment or and Activity. They don't share a common ancestor so I made it accept Any. I'd like a way to restrict it to only take Activity or Fragment objects. Is there anyway to do some sort of generics where it can take Class1 or Class2?

```
    fun requestLocationPermission(fragmentOrActivity: Any) {
    if (fragmentOrActivity is Fragment) {
        RxPermissions(fragmentOrActivity)
                .request(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                .subscribeBy(
                        onNext = { granted ->
                            if (!granted) {
                                fragmentOrActivity.toast(fragmentOrActivity.getString(location_message_locationPermissionRequired)) 
                            }
                        })
    } else if (fragmentOrActivity is FragmentActivity) {
        RxPermissions(fragmentOrActivity)
                .request(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                .subscribeBy(
                        onNext = { granted ->
                            if (!granted) {
                                fragmentOrActivity.toast(fragmentOrActivity.getString(location_message_locationPermissionRequired)) 
                            }
                        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just overload the function and have one version accept Activity and the other accept Fragment?

Comment: You will need an `Interface` that both of your `Fragment` & `FragmentActivity` will implement. Then you can use that `Interface` type in your function's parameter.

Comment: @Egor that wouldn't solve the code duplication issue.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to limit the function parameter to just two types, but you can still solve the code duplication issue with method overloading.

```
fun requestLocationPermission(fragment: Fragment) {
    requestLocationPermission(RxPermissions(fragment), fragment.getActivity())
}

fun requestLocationPermission(activity: FragmentActivity) {
    requestLocationPermission(RxPermissions(activity), activity)
}

private fun requestLocationPermission(rx: RxPermissions, context: Context) {
    rx.request(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            .subscribeBy(onNext = { granted -> 
                if (!granted) Toast.make(context, 
                        location_message_locationPermissionRequired, 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            })
}
```